# Concatenate nominal and numerical arrays to dataset (statistics toolbox)

Tags: matlab

I'm quite new to programming, so I apologize in advance in case I misuse some terminology.

My problem is the following:

I have one  142 x 1 nominal dataset array (CountryList) with unique country names and four 142 x 1 numerical arrays that contain infos about these countries. I want to bring them together into a single 142 x 5 dataset array 'CountryInfo'. The examples below only include one of the four numerical arrays I want to add, but I assume that if it works for one, the same applies for more.

I've tried a number of things, including

```
CountryInfo = join(CountryList, Info1, 'Type', 'leftouter')
```

which prompte the error

```
??? Undefined function or method 'join' for input arguments of type 'nominal'.
```

and

```
CountryInfo = horzcat(CountryList, Info1)
```

which prompted the error

```
All input arguments must be from the same categorical class.
```

I thought that using dataset class would allow me to concatenate arrays of different classes.

Should the above not make sense, please help me to be more clear.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
D1 = dataset({{'Spain';'USA';'France'}, 'CountryList'})
D2 = dataset({[20e6; 250e6; 50e6], 'Population'})
D3 = dataset({[3000;5000;3500], 'GDP'})
D = [D1 D2 D3]

>> D
D = 
    CountryList     Population    GDP 
    'Spain'           2e+07       3000
    'USA'           2.5e+08       5000
    'France'          5e+07       3500
>> size(D)
ans =
     3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, arrays/matrices contain only numbers and not strings. To mix types use cell arrays (using curly braces).

```
C1 = {'Spain';'USA'};
C2 = {45;7};
A3 = [3;4];
C3 = mat2cell(A3,[1 1]);
C = [C1 C2 C3]
```

output:

```
C = 

'Spain'    [45]    [3]
'USA'      [ 7]    [4]
```

Comment: The OP is asking about doing this using ``dataset`` arrays.  These are special containers in the Statistics Toolbox.